# How to send products with text options to create order bigcommerce API?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm having trouble creating an order to bigcommerce for products with text options, the api gives these error:

```
[
  {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "The options of one or more products are invalid.",
    "details": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "type": "InvalidProductOptionValue",
          "product": {
            "id": 3190,
            "name": "Esprit Knit Tech Gloves.",
            "product_option": {
              "id": 445,
              "option_id": 47,
              "display_name": "Name To Print",
              "value": "moni test",
              "url": "https:\/\/api.bigcommerce.com\/stores\/xxxxxx\/v2\/products\/3190\/options\/445",
              "resource": "\/products\/3190\/options\/445"
            },
            "url": "https:\/\/api.bigcommerce.com\/stores\/xxxxxx\/v2\/products\/3190",
            "resource": "\/products\/3190"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And what I'm sending for the products object is:

```
[
  {
    "product_id":"3190",
    "quantity":1,
    "product_options":[
       {
         "id":"445",
         "value":"TEXT option"
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

The code used works for product with drop down options. I don't know what else to send and I can't find an answer in their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have received an answer from bigcommerce saying that the API does not support TEXT options when creating orders.

This is their answer:
"I understand you are attempting to create an order with a text field as an option. Unfortunately, this type of product option object is not possible. The value attribute of the object will only accept integers (the id of the option value based off the option)."

Answer (score 0):

Have to checked if option exist?.

bigcommerce error 400 say: Issued when a malformed request was sent. Such as due to invalid syntax or missing required data. NOTE: Webhook requests missing Content-Type in the HTTP header will return a 400.

In the documentation say 'product_options' and you have typed 'product_option'

[bigcommerce create-an-order](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/orders#create-an-order)

i think it should be so:

```
"product": {
            "id": 3190,
            "name": "Esprit Knit Tech Gloves.",
            "product_options": [{
              "id": 445,
              "option_id": 47,
              "display_name": "Name To Print",
              "value": "moni test",
              "url": "https:\/\/api.bigcommerce.com\/stores\/xxxxxx\/v2\/products\/3190\/options\/445",
              "resource": "\/products\/3190\/options\/445"
            }],
            "url": "https:\/\/api.bigcommerce.com\/stores\/xxxxxx\/v2\/products\/3190",
            "resource": "\/products\/3190"
          }
```

For example:
if you product have two option with several values, then you have to set the two options values combination, and they have the stock level > 0:

product with id 49 and options:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 105
            [option_id] => 18
            [display_name] => Size
            [sort_order] => 0
            [is_required] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 106
            [option_id] => 3
            [display_name] => Color
            [sort_order] => 1
            [is_required] => 1
        )

)
```

option1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 68
            [option_id] => 18
            [label] => XS
            [sort_order] => 0
            [value] => XS
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 69
            [option_id] => 18
            [label] => S
            [sort_order] => 1
            [value] => S
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 70
            [option_id] => 18
            [label] => M
            [sort_order] => 2
            [value] => M
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 71
            [option_id] => 18
            [label] => L
            [sort_order] => 3
            [value] => L
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 72
            [option_id] => 18
            [label] => XL
            [sort_order] => 4
            [value] => XL
        )
)
```

option2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Silver
            [sort_order] => 1
            [value] => #cccccc
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Black
            [sort_order] => 2
            [value] => #000000
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Purple
            [sort_order] => 3
            [value] => #700170
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Blue
            [sort_order] => 4
            [value] => #123c91
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Green
            [sort_order] => 5
            [value] => #0f961e
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Yellow
            [sort_order] => 6
            [value] => #f0f005
        )
    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Orange
            [sort_order] => 7
            [value] => #e35e20
        )
    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Pink
            [sort_order] => 9
            [value] => #e841c1
        )
    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 39
            [option_id] => 3
            [label] => Red
            [sort_order] => 8
            [value] => #e60c0c
        )
)
```

simple order example:

```
array(
          "customer_id"=> 0,
          "status_id"=> 1,
          "base_shipping_cost"=> 0,
          "base_handling_cost"=> 0,
          "refunded_amount"=> 0,
          "order_is_digital"=> false,
          "staff_notes"=> "",
          "customer_message"=> "",
          "discount_amount"=> 10,
            "billing_address"=> array(
                "first_name"=> "Trisha",
                "last_name"=> "McLaughlin",
                "company"=> "",
                "street_1"=> "12345 W Anderson Ln",
                "street_2"=> "",
                "city"=> "Austin",
                "state"=> "Texas",
                "zip"=> "78757",
                "country"=> "United States",
                "country_iso2"=> "US",
                "phone"=> "",
                "email"=> "elsie@example.com"
              ),
              "products"=> array(
                array(
                  "product_id" => 49,
                  "quantity"   => 1,
                  "product_options"=> array(
                      array(
                          "id"   => 105,//product option id
                          "value"=> 68  //option value id
                      ),
                      array(
                          "id"   => 106,//product option id
                          "value"=> 7   //option value id
                      )
                  )
                )
              )
        ));
```

response:

```
object(stdClass)[10]
  public 'id' => int 24
  public 'customer_id' => int 0
  public 'date_created' => string 'Wed, 04 Mar 2015 16:55:54 +0000' (length=31)
  public 'date_modified' => string 'Wed, 04 Mar 2015 16:55:54 +0000' (length=31)
  public 'date_shipped' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'status_id' => int 1
  public 'status' => string 'Pending' (length=7)
  public 'subtotal_ex_tax' => string '90.0000' (length=7)
  public 'subtotal_inc_tax' => string '90.0000' (length=7)
  public 'subtotal_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'base_shipping_cost' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'shipping_cost_ex_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'shipping_cost_inc_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'shipping_cost_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'shipping_cost_tax_class_id' => int 0
  public 'base_handling_cost' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'handling_cost_ex_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'handling_cost_inc_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'handling_cost_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'handling_cost_tax_class_id' => int 0
  public 'base_wrapping_cost' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'wrapping_cost_ex_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'wrapping_cost_inc_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'wrapping_cost_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'wrapping_cost_tax_class_id' => int 0
  public 'total_ex_tax' => string '80.0000' (length=7)
  public 'total_inc_tax' => string '80.0000' (length=7)
  public 'total_tax' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'items_total' => int 1
  public 'items_shipped' => int 0
  public 'payment_method' => string 'Manual' (length=6)
  public 'payment_provider_id' => null
  public 'payment_status' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'refunded_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'order_is_digital' => boolean false
  public 'store_credit_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'gift_certificate_amount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'ip_address' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'geoip_country' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'geoip_country_iso2' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'currency_id' => int 1
  public 'currency_code' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  public 'currency_exchange_rate' => string '1.0000000000' (length=12)
  public 'default_currency_id' => int 1
  public 'default_currency_code' => string 'USD' (length=3)
  public 'staff_notes' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'customer_message' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'discount_amount' => string '10.0000' (length=7)
  public 'coupon_discount' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  public 'shipping_address_count' => int 1
  public 'is_deleted' => boolean false
  public 'ebay_order_id' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'billing_address' => 
    object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'first_name' => string 'Trisha' (length=6)
      public 'last_name' => string 'McLaughlin' (length=10)
      public 'company' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'street_1' => string '12345 W Anderson Ln' (length=19)
      public 'street_2' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'city' => string 'Austin' (length=6)
      public 'state' => string 'Texas' (length=5)
      public 'zip' => string '78757' (length=5)
      public 'country' => string 'United States' (length=13)
      public 'country_iso2' => string 'US' (length=2)
      public 'phone' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'email' => string 'elsie@example.com' (length=17)
  public 'order_source' => string 'external' (length=8)
  public 'external_source' => null
  public 'products' => 
    object(stdClass)[12]
      public 'url' => string 'https://store-qq6db7r.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders/24/products.json' (length=70)
      public 'resource' => string '/orders/24/products' (length=19)
  public 'shipping_addresses' => 
    object(stdClass)[13]
      public 'url' => string 'https://store-qq6db7r.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders/24/shippingaddresses.json' (length=79)
      public 'resource' => string '/orders/24/shippingaddresses' (length=28)
  public 'coupons' => 
    object(stdClass)[14]
      public 'url' => string 'https://store-qq6db7r.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders/24/coupons.json' (length=69)
      public 'resource' => string '/orders/24/coupons' (length=18)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what you have edited is the answer from the bigcommerce API, not what I send to them...what I send is below that code and it is an json array called "product_options", as the documentation states... you can find it in my question, the only problem is that the "value" contains a text and not an option value id, like in their example because my option is not of type SELECT, is of type TEXT.

Comment: you have to set de'option id' and the 'option value id'

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct and my code works for this case, but if the option is of type TEXT? meaning it does not have a set of values, but it's a string the buyer has to type when they add the product to cart...like a personalised text written on a shirt...that type of option does not have a set o values, but one value..the text written by the buyer...and that's the case I'm talking about, in this question..